# Sql Server: join order makes different execution plan, which one has better performance? WHY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

```
select * from AdventureWorks.Sales.Customer c
inner loop join AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader o on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID

select * from AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader o
inner loop join AdventureWorks.Sales.Customer c on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
```

In MS Sql Server: the above two statements can makes different execution plans.
If we assume table Customer and table SalesOrderHeader have very different order of magnitude of records. Which one has better performance? WHY?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does INNER JOIN performance depends on order of tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612208/does-inner-join-performance-depends-on-order-of-tables)

Answer (score 1):

Using join hints forces join order. Look into the messages tab: there is a message saying that.

This is a *very* unfortunate side-effect of using join-hints. It makes them very awkward to use.

> Which one has better performance?

Look at the query execution time and plan cost estimation to answer that.

Comment: If assuming that Customer has 100 records, SalesOrderHeader has 1,000,000 records, can we determine which one has better performance? Is it deterministic?

Comment: @user1033098, yes. "A nested loops join is particularly effective if the outer input is small and the inner input is preindexed and large." from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191318%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, cravoori! Getting into the bottom of the question.... WHY "A nested loops join is particularly effective if the outer input is small and the inner input is preindexed and large."?

Comment: Because the cost of the join is the number of outer rows times the cost to execute the inner input. Twice the rows on the outside => twice the cost. If inner input is not indexed a scan needs to occur. If it is indexed a cheap seek can be done.