# MySql In an inner join does it matter which table comes first?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm selecting data to output posts a user has book marked.

The main table which holds the `id`s of the `posts` a user has bookMarked, is called `bookMarks`. This is the table based on which `posts` will be selected from the `posts` table, to display to the user.

**bookMarks**

```
id  |  postId  |  userId
--------------------------
1   |  US01    |  1
2   |  US02    |  1
3   |  US01    |  2
4   |  US02    |  2
```

**posts**

```
id  |  postId  |  postTitle
--------------------------
1   |  US01    |  Title 1
2   |  US02    |  Title 2
3   |  US03    |  Title 3
4   |  US04    |  Title 4
```

My sql is currently like this:

```
select a.postsTitle
from posts a
inner join bookmarks b
  on b.userId = a.userId
  and b.userId = :userId
```

Notice, I have the table `posts` put first before the table `bookmarks`. But, since I'm selecting based on whats there in `bookmarks`, is it necessary I declare the table `bookmarks` first instead of `post` in the sql statement? Will doing it the way I'm doing it cause and problems in data selection or efficiency?

Or should I do it like:

```
select b.postsTitle
from bookmarks a
inner join posts b
  on a.userId = b.userId
  and a.userId = :userId
```

Notice, I have table `bookmarks` put first here.

Comment: In addition to m hasan's answer, by convention, where a WHERE clause is likely to place a condition on only one table, we tend to put that table first and then join the others onto it. But it's only a convention and makes no difference to the performance of an INNER JOIN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does INNER JOIN performance depends on order of tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612208/does-inner-join-performance-depends-on-order-of-tables)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of the following:

```
select a.postsTitle
from posts a
inner join bookmarks b
  on b.userId = a.userId
  and b.userId = :userId
```

You should consider formatting your JOIN in this format, using the `WHERE` clause, and proper capitalization:

```
SELECT p.postsTitle
FROM bookmarks b
INNER JOIN posts p
  ON p.userId = b.userId
WHERE b.userId = :userId
```

While it makes no difference (performance wise) to MySQL which order you put the tables in with `INNER JOIN` (MySQL treats them as equal and will optimize them the same way), it's convention to put the table that you are applying the `WHERE` clause to first. In fact, assuming proper indexes, MySQL will most likely start with the table that has the `WHERE` clause because it narrows down the result set, and MySQL likes to start with the set that has the fewest rows.

It's also convention to put the joined table's column first in the ON clause. It just reads more logically. While you're at it, use logical table aliases.

The only caveat is if you don't name your columns and instead use `SELECT *` like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM bookmarks b
INNER JOIN posts p
  ON p.userId = b.userId
WHERE b.userId = :userId
```

You'll get the columns in the order they're listed in the query. In this case, you'll get the columns for `bookmarks`, followed by the columns for `posts`.

Most would say never use `SELECT *` in a production query, but if you really must return all columns, and you needed the columns from `posts` first, you could simply do the following:

```
SELECT p.*, b.*
FROM bookmarks b
INNER JOIN posts p
  ON p.userId = b.userId
WHERE b.userId = :userId
```

It's always good to be explicit about the returned result set.

Comment: That `AND` in my question is where a `WHERE` actually is. I typed wrongly.

Comment: @Marcus Adams do you have any reference to back up the case that INNER JOIN order is not important. I have been trying to look for reference but cannot find any to cite.

Comment: @Nap, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/nested-join-optimization.html - "For join expressions involving only inner joins (and not outer joins), parentheses can be removed and joins evaluated left to right. In fact, tables can be evaluated in any order."

Answer (score 1):

There is no effect on query performance or final resultset with respect to placement of table on either side of JOIN clause if **INNER JOIN** is used .

The only difference observed is in order of columns returned and that too **only if** `SELECT *` is used . Suppose you have tableA(aid,col1,col2) and tableB(bid,col3)

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.aid=tableB.bid
```

returns column in order

```
aid|col1|col2|bid|col3
```

On otherhand

```
SELECT *
FROM tableB
INNER JOIN tableA
ON tableA.aid=tableB.bid
```

returns column in order

```
 bid|col3|aid|col1|col2|
```

But it matters in case of **LEFT JOIN** or **RIGHT JOIN**.